# Finding a Powershell Cmdlet to read a file from the "n"th byte

Tags: powershell

The Powershell Cmdlet [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) seems to be the most straightforward way to read a file's content but none of the switches associated with this Cmdlet seem to be able to read the file's content from the nth byte on wards, something similar to Notepad++'s ability to go to a particular offset in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods. I'm not sure if following one is the most straighforward one :)

```
$startByte = 5
Get-Content Test.txt -Raw -Encoding Byte | % { $_[$startByte ..($_.Length-1)] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do it to every line not the whole file. Meaning it will cut each line from x byte to the end. In this code it's byte 5.

```
Foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("c:\file.txt")) {
$line.substring(5,$(($line).length)-5)
}
```